# body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option server.js:11:20

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I am not getting the output, this is basically a simple login form, i am getting an error when I submit email id and password in the form.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const session = require('express-session');
const {v4:uuidv4} = require('uuid');
const router = require('./router');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT||3000;

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extends: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.set('view engine','ejs');
//load static assets
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')))
app.use(session({
    secret:'uuidv4()',
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:true
}))
app.use('/route', router);
//home route
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('base',{title:'Login System'});
})
app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log('Server started at port 3000')});
```

In browser:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

In command terminal:

body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option server.js
Server started at port 3000

Router Code:

```
const e = require('express');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const credentials = {
    email:'admin@gmail.com',
    password:'admin123'
}
router.post('/login', (res, req)=>{
    if(req.body.email == credentials.email && req.body.password == credentials.password)
    {
        req.session.user=req.body.email;
        //res.redirect('/dashboard');
        res.end('Login sucessful!');
    }
    else
    {
        res.end('Invalid username or password');
    }
})

module.exports=router;
```

This is the form Code that i used:

```
<%-include('header')-%>

<div class="text-center center-div" id="login">
  <div class="container w-25 border py-5">
    <div class="title">
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold">Login System</h2>
      <span>Login for existing users</span><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <form action="/route/login" method="POST" class="pt-3">
      <div class="frm-group">
        <input
          type="email"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="email"
          name="email"
        />
        <small class="form-text text-muted"
          >Register email address</small
        >
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="password"
          class="form-control"
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
        />
      </div>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<%-include('footer')-%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix your undefined issue Replace `extends` with `extended` and to get rid of the deprecation warning use `app.use(express.json());` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`
as you can see in [express github](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js) line 15 and 78 that body-parser is part of express

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i replaced extends with extended and used those two statements you told me to use. I am still getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined``` when i submit my email id and password.

Comment: Can you post your controller code where it says the email is undefined?

Comment: Sorry I am new to express, controller code means, terminal output?

Comment: No, like your route, where is "email"? you should have file name and line in the error output

Comment: Posted it in question.

Comment: One last thing, can you post the form? I assume you don't have a name value for your inputs

Comment: So I just noticed that you have your `req` and `res` set in the wrong order, `router.post('/login', (req, res) => {})` this should fix it

Comment: Actually to be accurate they are not in the wrong order but your order is setting the variable `res` to `request` and `req` to `response` you could actually do something like `res.body` but that's bad convention. Glad to help